# How to write and read variables from a text file

Tags: python, save, text-files

I want to know how to write and read variables from a text file. So if I'm doing a game, for example, I'll be able to save the player's progress.

In pseudo code:

```
variable = 1
# write to text file that variable = 1
# close program
# open program
variable
# Then IDLE should output 1
```

If you can help me out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importing text files with variables into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914864/importing-text-files-with-variables-into-python)

Comment: You basically import the text file using json, imp, or simply as a .py file defined as a module (__init__ file in folder), then to store, re-write the file.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell us that what have you tried?

Comment: If you need to store just `dict`, `list`, `str`, `int`,  `float`, `bool`, `None` you can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module.  If you need to store more complex types you can use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, with the caveat that "the `pickle` module is not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data," so you should "never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Nouman,  well I've done some research on how to write to txt etc. but I only found out how to print things. Also, Steven, please show me how to actually USE those modules because I'm kinda new to python just started like 3 months ago and I don't know very much about these custom modules and things like that.

Answer (score 3):

To write:

```
with open('game_vars.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(f'{score}\n{time}\n{high_score}\n')
```

To read:

```
with open('game_vars.txt', 'r') as file:
    score = int(file.readline().strip())
    time = int(file.readline().strip())
    high_score = int(file.readline().strip())
```