# Extract the value of a variable from a text file

Tags: python, replace, split, file-io

Following is the snippet of the text file (txt.toml):

```
value = 10.0
base = 14.0
outcome = 20.0
numbers = [12.0, 20.0]
input = false
Scheme = "default"
sigma = [1, 8, 11, 5]
```

I want to access the value of the variable "base". I tried the following solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915330/12526953):

```
variable = {}
with open('txt.toml', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, value = line.replace(' ', '').strip('=')
        variable[name] = value
        
print(variable['base'])
```

Following error is thrown:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am not able to fix this error. How can the value stored in the variable "base" be accessed?

Comment: You mean ```.split('=')```? ```.strip()``` will remove the ```=``` from the beginning and end of the string. Try ```name, value = line.replace(' ', '').spilt('=')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str.partition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to extract the `name` and the `value` part separated by an `"="`. Then you can use [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the whitespaces.

```
variable = {}
with open('txt.toml', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, _, value = line.partition('=')
        variable[name.strip()] = value.strip()
        
print(variable['base'])
```

```
$ python3 src.py 
14.0
```

This solution will work even if you have spaces in your source data and even if you have multiple equal `"="` signs in your values

**txt.toml**

```
...
Scheme = "default value here = (12 == 12.0)"
...
```

**code**

```
...
print(variable['Scheme'])
```

**output**

```
$ python3 src.py 
"default value here = (12 == 12.0)"
```

Answer (score 2):

use `split` instead of `strip`.

try this:

```
variable = {}
with open('txt.toml', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, value = line.replace(' ', '').split('=')
        variable[name] = value
        

variable
```

output:

```
{'value': '10.0\n',
 'base': '14.0\n',
 'outcome': '20.0\n',
 'numbers': '[12.0,20.0]\n',
 'input': 'false\n',
 'Scheme': '"default"\n',
 'sigma': '[1,8,11,5]'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `split` the string and not `strip` the string. `split` returns a list and `strip()` returns a string with the required substring removed from either side of the string.

`.split` will split the string into a list based on the delimiter and `.strip()` strips the string from the starting and beginning of the string.

```
variable = {}
with open('txt.toml', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, value = line.replace(' ', '').split('=')
        variable[name] = value
        
print(variable['base'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("txt.toml") as fd:
    lines = fd.read().splitlines()
lines = [line.split("=") for line in lines]
result =  {i[0].strip() : i[1].strip() for i in lines}
print(result)
print(result['base'])
```